# how to remove last n components from each element in a list in r

Tags: r, list

I have a vector called x.2 that I've provided a sample of 100 values

```
head(x.2, n=100)
```

> ```
>   [1]   6  10  12  14  15  18  20  21  22  24  26  28  30  33  34  35  36  38  39  40  42  44  45  46  48  50
>
> [27]  51  52  54  55  56  57  58  60  62  63  65  66  68  69  70  72  74  75  76  77  78  80  82  84  85  86
>
> [53]  87  88  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  98  99 100 102 104 105 106 108 110 111 112 114 115 116 117 118 119
>
> [79] 120 122 123 124 126 129 130 132 133 134 135 136 138 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148
> ```

The specific vector is not important.

I found all the places where the integers were at least consecutive by three numbers. To do this I used

```
L<-split(x.2, cumsum(c(1, diff(x.2) != 1)))

L.2<-L[lengths(L)>2]

L.2 has a bunch of elements with different lengths

L.2
```

> ```
> $`6`
> [1] 20 21 22
>
> $`11`
> [1] 33 34 35 36
>
> $`12`
> [1] 38 39 40
>
> $`14`
> [1] 44 45 46
>
> $`16`
> [1] 50 51 52
>
> $`17`
> [1] 54 55 56 57 58
> ...
> ```

Question:
how would you remove the last n integers from each element?

example:
n=2

```
> $`6` [1] 20
> 
> $`11` [1] 33 34
> 
> $`12` [1] 38
> 
> $`14` [1] 44
> 
> $`16` [1] 50
> 
> $`17` [1] 54 55 56 ...
```

and then how would I collapse this back into a vector?

Thanks!

Austin

Comment: `lapply(mylist, head, -3)` will remove the last 3 elements from each element in `mylist`. Is that what you want, or is it something to do with the consecutive numbers part?

Comment: I don't want to remove elements from a vector. I want to remove the last two integers of each list element. I need to something similar to lapply(L.2, `[[`, 1) which returns the first integer.

Comment: Yes, that answers the question! thanks!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan simple fix: x[1:(length(x)-n)]